# R call dplyr 1.0.0 filter() and across() within purrr::map()

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Here is code that reads data from a remote URL and then finds rows that are `NA`
for all columns within five different subsets of columns. The output table `miss_recode` gives the `ID`
for those rows along with the variable `recode_cols`, which is the label for
which subset of rows is all `NA`.

```
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))

urlRemote_path  <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/"
github_path <- "DSHerzberg/TOD-R/master/INPUT-FILES/"
fileName_path   <- "SO-data.csv"

input <- suppressMessages(read_csv(url(
  str_c(urlRemote_path, github_path, fileName_path)
)))

miss1 <- input %>%
  filter(across(c(i001:i035),
                ~ is.na(.))) %>% 
  mutate(recode_cols = "i001:i035")
miss2 <- input %>%
  filter(across(c(i036:i060),
                ~ is.na(.))) %>% 
  mutate(recode_cols = "i036:i060")
miss3 <- input %>%
  filter(across(c(i061:i100),
                ~ is.na(.))) %>% 
  mutate(recode_cols = "i061:i100")
miss4 <- input %>%
  filter(across(c(i101:i130),
                ~ is.na(.))) %>% 
  mutate(recode_cols = "i101:i130")
miss5 <- input %>%
  filter(across(c(i131:i165),
                ~ is.na(.))) %>% 
  mutate(recode_cols = "i131:i165")

miss_recode <- bind_rows(
  miss1, 
  miss2, 
  miss3, 
  miss4, 
  miss5
) %>% 
  select(ID, recode_cols)
```

I want to consolidate the code with `purrr::map`. The next snippet shows my
attempt, but it returns `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.`

```
vec <- c("i001:i035", "i036:i060", "i061:i100", "i101:i130", "i131:i165")

miss_recode_map <- vec %>% 
  map_df(~
        input %>%
        filter(across(c(!!sym(.x)),
                      ~ is.na(.))) %>% 
        mutate(recode_cols = .x) %>% 
          select(ID, recode_cols)
        )
```

Clearly I'm not getting the `NSE` right. This seems like a new question
related to `across()` which is now available in `dplyr` 1.0.0. In this
instance, it seems like one usage of `.x` requires the elements of `vec` to be
quoted, and the other usage of `.x` requires those elements to be unquoted.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert `"i001:i035"` as symbol, you actually need to parse it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

purrr::map_df(vec, ~input %>%
                    filter(across(!!parse_expr(.x),~ is.na(.))) %>%
                    mutate(recode_cols = .x) %>%
                    select(ID, recode_cols))

# A tibble: 8 x 2
#      ID recode_cols
#   <dbl> <chr>      
#1 201010 i036:i060  
#2 214063 i036:i060  
#3 262050 i036:i060  
#4 262063 i036:i060  
#5 205036 i061:i100  
#6 231007 i061:i100  
#7 208014 i101:i130  
#8 231014 i131:i165
```

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly the solution I was looking for. I will now go back and learn more about why parsing is the correct operation here.